# $ \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{5}{4} \times \frac{7}{8} \times \frac{11}{12} \times \cdots$ (just primes in the numerator)

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove the following equality?

$$ \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{5}{4} \times \frac{7}{8} \times \frac{11}{12} \times \frac{13}{12} \times \frac{17}{16} \times \frac{19}{20} \times \frac{23}{24} \times \frac{29}{28} \times \frac{31}{32} \times \cdots$$

I've seen this formula on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Other_infinite_series).

The numerators are the odd primes; each denominator is the multiple of four nearest to the numerator.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but how are you determining the denominators?

Comment: Hmm, the numerators are the primes, and the denominators are $p\pm 1$. Remains to see what rule they follow.

Comment: It looks like it's $d = p \pm 1$ such that $d \mod 4 = 0$.

Comment: It is $\mod 4$.

Comment: @Cortizol What? I mean, $\mod 4$, we have the primes $-1,1,-1,-1,1,\ldots$. Then just reverse the signs.

Comment: It looks very much like [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/372615/73025).

Comment: @O.L. I'm closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Although I have voted to close, after a more detailed examination it turns out to be not completely the same problem. Please leave it open! however, the author should explain the denominator $p_k+(-1)^{?}$.

Comment: @O.L. But the denominator follows the rule $p\pm1$ if $p\equiv \mp 1\mod 4$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff It is very close and can be solved using the same techniques but the identity itself is not the same. In my link, it was $p\pm1$ if $p\equiv\pm1\mod 4$ (note the sign difference). For example, in that identity $31$ would be divided by $30$, not by $32$.

Comment: @O.L. Ah, I see.

Comment: This is evaluating the $L$-function of the nontrivial character mod 4 at $s = 1$ through its Euler product, which is a lot more subtle to justify than evaluating the series for that $L$-function at $s = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment yesterday, this question is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372615/73025), except that here we want to prove the identity 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{\frac{p_{{k}}+1}{2}}}{p_{k}} \right )^{-1},
\end{align*}
which turns out to be even simpler.
So I almost literally reproduce the relevant half of my [previous solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372868/73025):

1. Decompose the product on the right as 
   $$B=\prod_{\text{primes}\; p\\ \text{ of  the  form }4k+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}\prod_{\text{primes}\; p\\ \text{ of  the  form }4k+3}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}.\tag{1}$$
2. Consider an odd integer $n=2m+1$. It is easy to understand that if primes of the form $4k+3$ appear in its prime number decomposition an even number of times, then $n$ is of the form $4K+1$ [since $(4k_1+3)(4k_2+3)=1\; \mathrm{mod}\;4$]. If the number of such appearances is odd, then $n$ is of the form $4K+3$.
3. Rewrite (1) (expanding its factors into geometric series) as
   $$B=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{r(m)}}{2m+1}$$
   where $r(m)$ counts the number of appearances of primes of the form $4k+3$ in the decomposition of $2m+1$. But then Step 2 allows to write $(-1)^{r(m)}=(-1)^m$, so that 
   $$ B=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{2m+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 12):

Your product is nothing but
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{\overset{p_k \leq n}{p_k \equiv -1 \pmod4}} \left(1+\dfrac1{p_k}\right)^{-1} \prod_{\overset{p_k \leq n}{p_k \equiv 1 \pmod4}} \left(1-\dfrac1{p_k}\right)^{-1}$$
Now recall that
$$\left(1-\dfrac1r\right)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{r^k}$$
Make use of the above to note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{\overset{p_k \leq n}{p_k \equiv -1 \pmod4}} \left(1+\dfrac1{p_k}\right)^{-1} \prod_{\overset{p_k \leq n}{p_k \equiv 1 \pmod4}} \left(1-\dfrac1{p_k}\right)^{-1} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{\ell=0}^m \dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{2\ell+1} = \dfrac{\pi}4$$
The last step makes use of the fact that
$$4\ell+1 = \prod_{\overset{q_k \equiv 1 \pmod4}{k=1,2,\ldots,n_1}} q_k^{a_k} \prod_{\overset{p_j \equiv -1 \pmod4}{j=1,2,\ldots,n_2}} p_j^{b_j}$$
such that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n_2}b_j = \text{even}$ and 
$$4\ell-1 = \prod_{\overset{q_k \equiv 1 \pmod4}{k=1,2,\ldots,n_1}} q_k^{a_k} \prod_{\overset{p_j \equiv -1 \pmod4}{j=1,2,\ldots,n_2}} p_j^{b_j}$$
such that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n_2}b_j = \text{odd}$.

Comment: Care to elucidate on the derivation of the final line?

Comment: @nbubis I have updated the post clarifying the last line.

Comment: The main thing to note is $$(1 \pm 1/p)^{-1} = 1 \mp 1/p + 1/p^2 \mp 1/p^3 + \cdots $$ If you multiply out the product, you can see each odd number $x$ appears exactly once in the form $1/x$ (with an appropriate sign). (the prime factorization of $x$ tells you which term to take from each factor to make $1/x$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $L(s,\chi)$ be the $L$ function for the non principal modulo $4$ Dirichlet 
character

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=L(1,\chi)=\prod_{p}\frac{p}{p-\chi(p)}=\prod_{p\equiv 1 \text{mod 4}}\frac{p}{p-1}\prod_{p\equiv 3 \text{mod 4}}\frac{p}{p+1}$$